# Variable declaration versus assignment syntax

Tags: language-design, syntax, language-features

Working on a statically typed language with type inference and streamlined syntax, and need to make final decision about syntax for variable declaration versus assignment. Specifically I'm trying to choose between:

```
// Option 1. Create new local variable with :=, assign with =
foo := 1
foo = 2

// Option 2. Create new local variable with =, assign with :=
foo = 1
foo := 2
```

Creating functions will use `=` regardless:

```
// Indentation delimits blocks
square x =
    x * x
```

And assignment to compound objects will do likewise:

```
sky.color = blue
a[i] = 0
```

Which of options 1 or 2 would people find most convenient/least surprising/otherwise best?

Comment: Why do you need differentiate between the two? Edit: To clarify, why can't you make `foo = ...` always introduce or assign to a local, with syntax to exempt one name from the "introducing" part, instead making `=` alter a global/closed over variable  (i.e. , like Python's `global` and `nonlocal`, possibly unified into one concept)?

Comment: If by type inference you mean implicit declaration of variables, may I refer you to the ALGOL committee's remarks?  They roundly boxed Tony Hoare's ears when he suggested adding FORTRAN-style implicit declaration to ALGOL.

This was before the (possibly apocryphal) story of a lost interplanetary probe from a typographical error combined with implicit declaration, that converted a FORTRAN DO-statement into a legal assignment statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many more aspects one should consider when settling for assignment/declaration syntax, than simple `=` vs. `:=` bikeshedding.

Type inference or not, you *will* want a syntax for explicit type annotations. In some type systems, inference may not be possible without occasional explicit annotations. There two possible classes of syntax for this:

1. A type-variable statement without further operators implies a declaration, e.g. `int i` in *C*. Some languages use postfix types like `i int`, (*Golang* to a certain degree).
2. There is a typing operator, often `:` or `::`. Sometimes, this declares the type of a name: `let i : int = 42` (e.g. *Ocaml*). In an interesting spin of this, *Julia* allows a programmer to use type assertions for arbitrary expressions, along the lines of `sum = (a + b):int`.

You may also want to consider an explicit declaration keyword, like `var`, `val` or `let`. The advantage is not primarily that they make parsing and understanding of the code much easier, but that they unambiguously introduce a variable. Why is this important?

- If you have closures, you need to precisely declare which scope a variable belongs to. Imagine a language without a declaration keyword, and implicit declaration through assignment (e.g. *PHP* or *Python*). Both of these are syntactically challenged with respect to closures, because they either ascribe a variable to the outermost or innermost possible scope. Consider this Python:

  ```python
  def make_closures():
    x = 42;
    def incr():
      x = x + 1
    def value():
      print(x)
    return incr, value

  i, v = make_closures();
  v();  # expected: 42, behaviour: error because x is uninitialized in value()
  ```

  Compare with a language that allows explicit declaration:

  ```javascript
  var make_closures = function() {
    var x     = 42,
        incr  = function() { x++ },
        value = function() { console.log(x) };
    return { incr: incr, value: value };
  };

  var closures = make_closures();
  closures.value();  // everything works
  ```
- Explicit declarations allow variable shadowing. While generally a bad practice, it sometimes makes code much easier to follow – no reason to disallow it.
- Explicit declarations offer a form of typo detection, because unbound variables are not implicitly declared. Consider:

  ```python
  var1 = 42
  if 0 < 1:
     varl = 12

  print(var1)  # 42
  ```

  versus:

  ```perl
  use strict;
  my $var1 = 42;
  $varl = 12 if 0 < 1;  # Doesn't compile: Global symbol "$varl" requires explicit package name
  say $var1;
  ```

You should also consider whether you would like to (optionally) enforce single-assignment form, e.g through keywords like `val` (*Scala*), `let`, or `const` or by default. In my experience, such code is easier to reason about.

How would a short declaration e.g. via `:=` fare in these points?

- Assuming you have typing via a `:` operator and assigment via `=`, then `i : int = 42` could declare a variable, the syntax `i : = 42` would invoke inference of the variable, and `i := 42` would be a nice contraction, but not an operator in itself. This avoids problems later on.
- Another rationale is the mathematical syntax for the declaration of new names `x := expression` or `expression =: x`. However, this has no significant difference to the `=` relation, except that the colon draws attention to one name. Simply using the `:=` for similarity to maths is silly (considering the `=` abuse), as is using it for similarity to *Pascal*.
- We can declare some more or less sane characteristics for `:=`, like:

  - It declares a new variable in the current scope
  - which is re-assignable,
  - and performs type inference.
  - Re-declaring a variable in the same scope is a compilation error.
  - Shadowing is permitted.

  But in practice, things get murky. What happens when you have multiple assignments (which you should seriously consider), like

  ```
  x := 1
  x, y := 2, 3
  ```

  Should this throw an error because `x` is already declared in this scope? Or should it just assign `x` and declare `y`? *Go* takes the second route, with the result that typo detection is weakened:

  ```
  var1 := 1
  varl, var2 := 2, 3  // oops, var1 is still 1, and now varl was declared
  ```

  Note that the “RHS of typing-operator is optional” idea from above would disambiguate this, as every new variable would have to be followed by a colon:

  ```
  x: = 1
  x:, y: = 2, 3  # error because x is already declared
  x,  y: = 2, 3  # OTOH this would have been fine
  ```

Should `=` be declaration but `:=` be assignment? Hell no. First, no language I know of does this. Second, when you don't use single-assignment form, then assignment is more common than declaration. Huffman-coding of operator requires that the shorter operator is used for the more common operation. But if you don't generally allow reassignment, the `=` is somewhat free to use (depending on whether you use `=` or `==` as comparison operator, and whether you could disambiguate a `=` from context).

#### Summary

- If assignment and declaration use the *same* operator, bad things happen: Closures, variable shadowing, and typo detection all get ugly with implicit declarations.
- But if you don't have re-assignments, things clear up again.
- Don't forget that explicit types and variable declarations are somewhat related. Combining their syntax has served many languages well.
- Are you sure you want such little visual distinction between assignment and declaration?

#### Personal opinion

I am fond of declaration keywords like `val` or `my`. They stand out, making code easier to grok. Explicit declarations are always a good idea for a serious language.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using `:` for optional explicit type, so as you say, `i := 42` is shorthand for `i: int = 42`. I am allowing reassignment by default (so there needs to be some distinction), but it can be disabled with a `final` modifier as in Java. And I'm not a huge fan of declaring multiple variables on one line so I'm okay with losing that.

Answer (score 1):

**Both alternatives are bad.**  The first because it is far from obvious that a `:=` operator creates a local variable, and the second because it means you have two different meanings for the `=` operator.  Learn Dennis Ritchie's lesson, and don't have two operators that *appear* to be assignments, one of which is not.

Comment: Further, if I see `:=`, I assume pascal assignment. That also means I expect `=` to test equality, not declare a variable.

Comment: Trying to read a source code without understanding its notation is bad habit. And your "obvious" point won't work when you know the notation. Otherwise `:=` and `=` are visually distinguishable very well.

Comment: @lorus Tell that to every seasoned C programmer who's typed `if (a = b) ...`.  It's not just a rookie mistake, everyone does it once in a while.  In other words, it's a language design flaw.

Comment: This problem with C syntax is that assignment is an expression. If it would be a statement, the problem won't occur.

Answer (score 1):

New variables should be declared with `x := 5` and should be updated/reassigned with `x = 5`. Kind of the norm now, eight years later. Mostly thanks to golang I think.